# How to execute the file at different location in nodejs

Tags: node.js, child-process

I have to run file test.js which is at different location than the my running application. To do that i have tried the fallowing code

```
var execFile = require("child_process").execFile;
exports.sync = function(req, res) {
    console.log("sync called");
    var child = execFile("C:/Users/rhush/Desktop/test", function(error, stdout, stderr) {
        if (error) {
            throw error;
        }
        console.log(stdout);
        res.send({ status: stdout });
    });
};
```

and my test file is here :

```
function testing() {
    console.log('sync job running');
}
testing();
```

but i got the error [image]

please correct if i am doing any mistake.

Comment: Given you are executing `test.js` should the path `"C:/Users/rhush/Desktop/test"` be `"C:/Users/rhush/Desktop/test.js" ` instead?

Comment: No that's also not work for me..

Comment: Also - specifying the file name is not enough. It won't do anything because the file is not executable. Depending on how that file will be ran, if you are intending to run it with `node` binary then it would be like `node C:/Users/rhush/Desktop/test.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run a js file using execFile you need to pass node command with file name, Use this one:

```
var execFile = require("child_process").execFile;
exports.sync = function(req, res) {
    console.log("sync called");

    var child = execFile("node", ["C:/Users/rhush/Desktop/test.js"], function(error, stdout, stderr) {
        if (error) {
            throw error;
        }
        res.send({ status: stdout });
    });
};
```

Comment: I don't think u would use node to run the test. I was just quoting an example. People typically do it in mocha or jesmine

Comment: @SamuelToh This is just an example for execFile node child_process. Not any TDD code.